# Combining RGB layer with DSM layer to get new layer with 4 bands

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am a beginner in GIS.

I have 2 layers, one having RGB bands while other having a DSM gray band.

How do I combine them to get a layer having 4 bands altogether?

I have tried using following tools Merge, r.composite, virtual layer.

```
Data type   Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
Extent  476690.6698999999789521,7222409.4579999996349216 : 477996.2334000000264496,7223816.8580000000074506 
Width   29589
Height  31897
pixel size: 4.4cm
Projection : UTM 6N
```

Comment: Do all the layers have the same pixel size and coordinate system?

Comment: Do you actually want to create a [shaded relief map/image](https://www.google.com/search?q=shaded+relief+map)? Putting the DSM into the RGB as a 4th band will definitely *not* give you that.

Comment: @user2856 Yes I want to create a shaded relief map/ image. I only want to add a layer which has all 4 bands in it. I found another way, I split the layer bandwise and combined them together which ultimately gave me 4 bands. Sorry for the late reply. I would appreciate it if you could provide any easier process.

Comment: No sorry, splitting to single bands then recombining and including the additional single band raster is the easiest way. Though you can avoid writing the bands as raster data to file by writing to virtual (VRT) raster files (just small xml text files).  That still not how to create a shaded relief image though.

Comment: Oh well, then it is done. Thanks!